# Bind modal popup with the data from the row in angular 4

Tags: angular, popup, ngx-bootstrap

here I have a small crud angular app, my question is, how to get Id of the employee that's shown in the table row, so I can make a delete request which should be confirmed(triggered, I don't know) when the popup modal pops up...

Here is my class of employee

```
export class employee {
Id: string;
FirstName: string; 
Email: string;

 }
```

And in my service

```
    deleteEmployee(emp: employee) { 
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.delete(url +  emp.Id);
    }
```

And in my component

```
   DeleteEmployee(e: employee) {

  this._usermanagementservice.deleteEmployee(this.Demoemployee).subscribe(res 
  => {
        this.LoadAllEmployees();
    });
}
   DeleteEmp() {
    this.DeleteEmployee(this.Demoemployee);
    this.LoadAllEmployees();
    this.modalRef.hide();
    }
```

With the call for the ngx bootstrap modal

```
  openModalDelete(templateDelete: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(templateDelete, this.config);
  }
```

And in my component.html

```
 <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped" id="billing_history_table">
    <thead class="head">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let e of employeelist">
            <td>{{e.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{e.positionId}}</td>
            <td>{{e.email}}</td>

            <td><a (click)="openModalDelete(templateDelete)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And template of templateDelete with the confirm button that should call DeleteEmp function(I guess)

```
    <ng-template #templateDelete>
    <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p>Do you want to confirm?</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
    (click)="confirm()">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    (click)="decline()">No</button>
    </div>
```

**Noted that I have no issues with the api, or any errors in general, other parts of my app works just fine(like add new thru form, and else), and the popup modal works, opens small confirm dialog in which Yes button works(prints out some message on console etc.) I'm not sure, how can I get Id of the employee of the same row and then open modal which should take that id and pass it to my delete function called from component**

I apologize for my bad english, I hope someone understood my issue :/

PS. I've tried calling it directly, without popup, straigt from the row, clicking on glyphicon, and got back error...

Comment: Your modalService should handle this. Did you write your own modalService or are you using a ready-made one ?

Comment: ready made on from ngx bootstrap

Comment: anyone? still searching how to bind data to my popup modal :/

Comment: I don't know about ngx bootstrap. But you can use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples
You can pass inputs to the modal component with: 
`this.modalRef.componantInstace.input = 'value' `